# Envelope of oscillator signal

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

How do we find envelope ODE of a modulated oscillator obeying

$$y^{''}(t)+y (t)\left(\dfrac{2 \pi}{t-c}\right)^2 = 0 $$

after obtaining solution say for initial conditions $y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0?$. Does it oscillate indefinitely?

Could not readily apply $\; c-, p-$  discriminant methods. Please help.

Numerical solution with $ c=t _{max} =6$

[image]

Envelope sketched by hand.

Answer (score 4):

If I did not make any mistake, the solution is given by
$$y=\frac{1}{k }\sqrt{\frac{c-t}{c}} \left(\sin \left(\frac{k}{2} \log \left(\frac{c}{c-t}\right)\right)+k \cos
   \left(\frac{k}{2}  \log \left(\frac{c}{c-t}\right)\right)\right)$$ where $k=\sqrt{16\pi^2-1}$.

Now, close to $c^-$, $y$ oscillates indefinitely.

**Edit**

Defining $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{c-t}{c}}$, we have
$$y=\alpha  \left(\cos [k \log (\alpha )]-\frac{1}{k}\sin [k \log (\alpha )]\right)$$

The first derivative cancels at
$$t_n=c \left(1-e^{\frac{2 \pi  n}{k}}\right)$$ At these points
$$y(t_n)=(-1)^n e^{\frac{ \pi  n}{k}}\qquad \text{and}\qquad y''(t_n)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1+k^2}{4c^2}e^{-\frac{2 \pi  n}{k}}$$

So, if $n$ is odd, these points correspond to maxima and, if $n$ is even, they correspond to minima and then the upper and lower envelopes.

Comment: Omg! shall upload its numeric solution..

Comment: @Narasimham. I am sorry to ask the question. Did you know/use the analytical solution (hoping that mine is correct) ?

Comment: Don't know any analytic solutions sir .. only fiddled with the harmonic  motion argument.

Comment: contd.. Actually context is a good question here  imho that got too soon closed, it is involving a cosine curve modification somewhat like a frequency modulated cosine wave. I am unable to see it again now. Wanted to answer it, however could n't. This question is  out of it and  related.  Thanks for the answer. It is correct, and is a product of two functions.

Comment: contd.. By inspection the solution is found to have two parts. The coefficient  is the modulating function ( a parabola profile modulating signal component) multiplied by a  frequency modulation related cosine wave of constant amplitude (unity here) but varying frequency. How is the former isolated? By inspection? Is this a method or a standard  procedure?

Comment: @Narasimham. I put some more material about the envelopes.

Comment: Thanks...let me have some insight into the class of odes with  "in-built modulating  .waveforms"

Answer (score 2):

If you set $x=t-c$, then $$x^2y''(x+c)+4\pi^2y(x+c)=0$$ is an **Euler-Cauchy equation** with characteristic polynomial
$$
0=r(r-1)+4\pi^2=(r-\tfrac12)^2+4\pi^2-\tfrac14
$$
which has for the domain $x<0$ basis solutions $(-x)^{\frac12\pm iω}=(-x)^{\frac12}e^{\pm iω\ln(-x)}$ which combine to the real basis solutions
$$
(-x)^{\frac12}\cos(\omega\ln(-x)+\phi_0)
~\text{ and }~
(-x)^{\frac12}\sin(\omega\ln(-x)+\phi_0),
$$
where $ω=\frac12\sqrt{16\pi^2-1}$. The initial conditions and setting $\phi_0=-\ln(c)$ then lead to the formula in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. By inspection the solution is found to have two parts. The coefficient  is the modulating function ( a parabola profile modulating signal component) multiplied by a  frequency modulation related cosine wave of constant amplitude (unity here) but varying frequency. How is the former isolated? By inspection? Is this a method or a standard  procedure?